# whats the difference between the <u> tag and the <ins> tag?

Tags: html

what's the difference between these two tags? seems to do the same thing.

```
<p>My favorite color is  <ins>red</ins>!</p>
```

and

```
<p>My favorite color is  <u>red</u>!</p>
```

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/18/html5-semantics/

Comment: `<u>` is deprecated. `<ins>` is not. [Kind of.](http://html5doctor.com/u-element/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The official difference depends on the HTML specification or draft that you choose to regard as official.

By the HTML 4.01 specification, `u` means underlined text style, whereas `ins` means that its content has been “inserted [...] with respect to a different version of a document (e.g., in draft legislation where lawmakers need to view the changes). The rendering of `ins` is not specified; instead, some possible renderings are described. In practice, browsers mostly use underlining. There is also the formal syntactic difference that `u` allows text-level content only, whereas `ins` may contain blocks, too.

In the HTML5 drafts, `ins` is essentially similar but with different wordings and with an explicit suggestion, or maybe (semi)recommendation, that the default rendering use underlining (see [10.3.4 Phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#phrasing-content-1) there). The `u` was previously excluded from the draft, now added but with invented meaning: “The u element represents a span of text with an unarticulated, though explicitly rendered, non-textual annotation, such as labeling the text as being a proper name in Chinese text (a Chinese proper name mark), or labeling the text as being misspelt.” If this does not make sense to you, you’re not the only one. And `u` has underlining as the suggested, or recommended, default rendering.

In practice, the effect is mostly the same, except that `ins` tags are ignored by some old browsers. Some exotic browser could use different rendering. I have not seen any evidence of any browser, search engine, or any other relevant software make any distinction between the two; their “semantic difference” has no practical impact.

However, I would not use `ins` for anything except inserted text in some sense, just because some future browsers might treat it in some way that makes sense for inserted text but not otherwise. And there would be no tangible benefit from using `ins` just for underlining: `u` is shorter markup and more widely supported. Then again, situations where you should underline text, except links, on web pages are rare.

Answer (score 14):

Semantics. The `<ins>` tags means content inserted after it was first published. The `<u>` tag is simply for underlining and has no meaning.

Reference: [`<ins>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/ins), [`<u>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/u)

Answer (score 4):

`ins` is a semantic tag : it denotes an element which has been inserted (see also `del` for deleted elements) while `u` gives the engine the instruction to render the element as underline.

Some engines may decide to render `ins` as `u` but you can use the "semantic meaning" to decide to render it otherwise (with CSS). Speaking of CSS, it renders `<u>` useless and just makes style maintenance more difficult, just like `<b>`, `<center>`, and so on.

As for the other edition tag, `del`, it's not widely used and it's not really clear why it should be.

Reference :

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ins.html

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/del.html

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/u.html

Comment: Ins was around since at least HTML4.0. U is obsolete in HTML5 though, since there isn't really any use for it.

Answer (score 2):

1. `ins` has a meaning: This text was inserted at a later date.
2. `u` has no meaning, it just tells the browser to put some underlining on it. (Though CSS can override that just as for any other element, one of the reasons this element has been pointless since 4.0)
3. `ins` was introduced with 4.0, and is still current.
4. `u` was introduced with at least 2.0 (HTML1.0 never really stopped being work-in-progress so 2.0 was the first real standard), and deprecated with 4.0
5. `u` is inline-only, so `<p><u>this is valid</u></p>` but `<u><p>this makes no sense</p></u>`. `ins` is one of the very few elements that can be both block and inline (a few more inline elements were given this status with 5.0), so `<p><ins>this is valid</ins></p><ins><p>this is also valid</p></ins>`.
6. `ins` has an optional `cite` attribute giving the URI of a document (or fragment within a document, perhaps the same document it is in) explaining the change, and `datetime` giving the date of the change in the a [W3 date-time format](http://www.hackcraft.net/web/datetime/#w3cdtf).

Hence:

1. If the underline is to indicate something added, use `ins`.
2. If you want to indicate something added, but not by underlining, use `ins` and use CSS to change how it appears.
3. Don't use `u` ever. HTML's history is a nightmare from which we are trying to awake.
4. If you want underline for another reason, then either pick the element that best matches your meaning, using `div` or `span` if you really can't do any better, and use CSS to underline it.

Comment: `<u>` is not obsolete in HTML5. It has been a conforming element since April 2011. See http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2011Apr/0212.html

Comment: Thanks for that @Alohci (And for that matter, I think it was the better decision, either take out b and i too, or leave u in).